# Fat-Free PHP Switch Language on the fly

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

How is it possible to switch language on the fly? I have 2 dictionnaries and even if I try to set `$f3->language('en')`; or `$f3->set->LANGUAGE('en')`; nothing seems to work. I always return in french.

I created a route `/lang/switch/@lang` and everything is fine at getting the `PARAMS.lang` but I can't seem to be able to change the language on the fly in any way.

I'm using the latest version of Fat-Free PHP 3.6.

Comment: [The docs](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/views-and-templates#MultilingualSupport) seem to suggest this: `$f3->set('LANGUAGE','en');` So you were close.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the problem is coming from the rerouting after changing the LANGUAGE variable.

`$f3->route('GET /lang/switch/@lng', 
function($f3) {

$f3->set('LANGUAGE', $f3->get('PARAMS.lng'));

$f3->reroute($f3->get('SERVER.HTTP_REFERER'));

});`

Comment: I think that the `->set` is per request. I should store the language in the session and set it back in the controllers. What do you think?

Comment: @JonathanPouliot you're right, that's the way to go.